# html file is not displaying which is referenced inside another html file using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

main.py

```
`from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')`
```

home.html

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>HOME</h1>
  <a href="hello.html">hello</a>
</body>
</html>`
```

hello.html

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>`
```

[home.html is displaying while clicking the address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq6DT.png)
[hello.html is not displaying while clicking the hyper link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLHEe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

In main.py: Created new @app.route('/hi') that returns hello.html when called from home.html (see below)

In home.html: Changed href="hello.html" To href="/hi" to call that Flask route:

Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/hi')
def hi_there():
    return render_template('hello.html')


app.run()
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>HOME</h1>
  <a href="/hi">hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a route in your main.py file for the hello.html page. You need to add a new route that maps to the URL path /hello.html and returns the hello.html template.